# Como alinhar texto com o centro da div com Materialize?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, materialize

Possuo uma div com um texto e uma imagem:

[image: div sem destacamento]
[image: div com área destacada em azul]

Essa div possui um bloco de texto que deve ser alinhado com o centro. Pra fazer o alinhamento, usei a classe `.valign-wrapper`, que funcionou perfeitamente com a imagem. Porém, ao aplicar a classe, ela só tem efeito sobre a imagem, ignorando o parágrafo anexado ao lado.

Como eu posso alinhar esse bloco de texto?

**Estrutura do DOM**

```
<div class="valign-wrapper">
  <div class="col s12 l6">
      <div class="col s12 l5 center-align">
        <p><img class="responsive-img circle" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="avatar"/></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 l7 center-align valign-wrapper">
        <p class="user">
          <span>
            <small class="message">Bem vindo,</small><br/> <strong id="user-name">Fulano da Silva</strong>
          </span> <br/>
          <span class="phone">(51) 9 9999 - 9999 </span><br/>
          <span class="mail">fulano.silva42@gmail.com</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS utilizado**

```
.avatar p.user{
  color: #455a64;
  line-height: 102%;
  margin-left: 0.2em;
}

span.phone, span.mail, small.message{
  font-size: 12px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

strong#user-name{
  font-size: 16px;
}

.avatar img{
  width: auto;
  max-width: 7em;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: qual versão do materialize?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara basicamente vc está usando a classe na div errada, e classe `valign-wrapper` é isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja é um `container flex`, com `align-items: center`. Porém só os filhos diretos desse `container` vão alinhar no centro, e vc colocou a classe no avó

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Veja que corrigindo isso tudo se alinha**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
  
  .avatar p.user{
  color: #455a64;
  line-height: 102%;
  margin-left: 0.2em;
}

span.phone, span.mail, small.message{
  font-size: 12px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

strong#user-name{
  font-size: 16px;
}

.avatar img{
  width: auto;
  max-width: 7em;
  height: auto;
}
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col s6">

            <div class="valign-wrapper">
                <div class="col s12 l6 valign-wrapper">
                    <div class="col s12 l5 center-align">
                      <p><img class="responsive-img circle" src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="avatar"/></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s12 l7 center-align valign-wrapper">
                      <p class="user">
                        <span>
                          <small class="message">Bem vindo,</small><br/> <strong id="user-name">Fulano da Silva</strong>
                        </span> <br/>
                        <span class="phone">(51) 9 9999 - 9999 </span><br/>
                        <span class="mail">fulano.silva42@gmail.com</span>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col s6">6-columns (one-half)</div>
      </div>

  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```